# Please make sure that the outcome column is a factor or numeric. The class(es) of the column: 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame'

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the caret package to cross-validate a model that I made. but I receive an error "make sure outcome column is a factor or numeric". How it must be solved?

```
#install.packages("readxl")
library("readxl")
Data <- read_excel("")
library(tidyverse)
library(earth)
library(caret)
#creat train split (80/20)
train <- sample(1:nrow(Data), size=floor(0.8*nrow(Data)),replace = FALSE)
Train <- Data[train,]
Test <- Data[-train,]
#exept column 1 are predictors and column 1 is the target
x <- Train[, -1]
y <- Train[, 1]
#prameter tuning
Parameter <- floor(expand.grid(degree=1:4, nprune=seq(5,50,by=5)))
#perform cross-validation
cv_mars <- train(
  x = x,
  y = y,
  method = "earth",
  metric = "RMSE",
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
  tuneGrid = Parameter_grid )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the first bug. x and y must be converted using data. matrix

```
#install.packages("readxl")
library("readxl")
Data <- read_excel("")
#install.packages("caret") 
#install.packages("tidyverse")   
#install.packages("earth")        
library(tidyverse)
library(earth)
library(caret)
#creat train split (80/20)
train <- sample(1:nrow(Data), size=floor(0.8*nrow(Data)), replace = FALSE)
Train <- Data[train,]
Test <- Data[-train,]
#exept column 1 are predictors and column 1 is target
x <- Train[, -1]
y <- Train[, 1]
df1 <- data.matrix(x)
df2 <- data.matrix(y)
#prameter tuning
Parameter <- floor(expand.grid(degree=1:4, nprune=seq(5,50,by=5)))
#perform cross-validation
cv_mars <- train(
  x = df1,
  y = df2,
  method = "earth",
  metric = "RMSE",
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
  tuneGrid = Parameter_grid )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x <- Train[, -1]
y <- Train$variable_name
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Marco, appreciate for the comment.